# While running VB6 I get no notifications/sounds from Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vb6

I have some legacy code that I need to occasionally maintain in VB6.  My issue is that when I run VB6 and run code at least once, Outlook will stop notifications and I won't know if an email comes in until I switch apps and see the unread email count.  At times I get focused in testing and don't switch for quite some time missing some important emails that need responding to.

Has anyone else run into this and is there something to look at or fix?

It's not just starting the VB6 application.  I can start it and leave it alone and all notifications work up until I actually run some code.  Then nothing until I close VB6 completely.

And it's not some specific code in an existing program.  I can start a blank project, run it, and the same thing happens.

I had Office 2013 and it was happening then, and now upgraded to Office 365, and the same thing is happening.

I seem to get other notifications, like from Chrome, or other apps, so it appears to just be Outlook or Office (or at least for what I have installed).

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Could it be some VB6 IDE add-in that is causes this? Like an email plugin?

Comment: The only plugin I have is the mouse wheel fix so I can scroll the code in the IDE.  Pretty sure this came from MS, though.